# Tailwindcss not working when I build Next.js App

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a Chrome Extension using Nextjs.

I followed this article - https://birdeatsbug.com/blog/build-a-chrome-extension-in-next-js-and-notion-api

When I run the code using dev mode (`npm run dev`), `tailwindcss` is working fine.

But when I build (`npm run build` or `npm run start`), it's not working.

`nextjs version: 12.1.6`

`tailwindcss version: ^3.1.4`

Here is my code:

`tailwind.config.css`

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
  ],
}
```

`postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {
      config: join(__dirname, 'tailwind.config.js'),
    },
    autoprefixer: {}
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```
 {
  "name": "demoproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && next export && mv out/_next out/next && sed -i '' -e 's/\\/_next/\\.\\/next/g' out/**.html && mv out/index.html ../extension && rsync -va --delete-after out/next/ ../extension/next/ && rm -rf out && rsync -va --delete-after public/next-assets ../extension/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.6.5",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "eslint": "8.18.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "watch": {
    "build": {
      "patterns": [
        "styles/**",
        "pages/**",
        "public/**",
        "helpers/**",
        "next.config.js"
      ],
      "ignore": [
        "out",
        "node_modules",
        ".next",
        ".vscode"
      ],
      "extensions": [
        "js",
        "json"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`next.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
  }
  
  module.exports = {
    images: {
      loader: 'akamai',
      path: '',
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the tailwind css directive in `global.css` like this

```
@tailwind base;

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

See whether it works..

Comment: tried it, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

always put you css files inside app directory,and dont put it in public file that work for me.